# Two elements under each other sharing the available height in a fixed-height container

Tags: html, css

I have difficulty phrasing this question correctly, but I'd like to have two divs sharing the same height in a fixed-height container. So the #container element would have a fixed height of e.g. 500px; the #upper and #lower elements can grow taller and smaller during their lifetimes, but can never exceed 500px. If the two inner elements start overlapping they should reach a maximum height and let users employ scrollbars.

I included a picture to clear things up:

[image]

And some sample (non-working) CSS that conceptually shows what I'd like to do:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 500px;
}

#upper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 10%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#lower {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-height: 10%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I could but I'd prefer a CSS-only solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following bellow, but this would be easier if I had something than my imagination to work with.

http://codepen.io/DanielMinett/pen/uEdFv

```
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height:500px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 15px;
  position:relative
}

#upper {
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  min-height: 10%;
  max-height: 90%;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#lower {
  background-color: #EE8833;
  min-height: 10%;
  max-height: 90%;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
```

Comment: Edited my answer.  Checkout the Code Pen link to see it in action with a visual aid very similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks, but your example wouldn't take care of the elements overlapping. I went with a JS solution; just measuring the elements' actual height and working with that.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

Limiting the height of an element to its parent's height (or a percentage of) is possible.

Limiting it dynamically based on the height of another element is not possible, and will require an actual programming language (i.e. javascript).

As a sidenote, the only situations I can envisage where you would need this functionality (rather than just setting say, max-height:50%; on both elements) are where you'd be populating the elements using javascript anyway...?